# react-native picker is not showing array items

Tags: react-native

React-native picker is not showing array items. Could you please help?

Here is my code:

```
    <Picker
      selectedValue={this.state.category}   
      onValueChange={itemValue => this.setState({category: itemValue})}> 
      {this.props.categoryList.map((item,index) =>             
        <Picker.Item label={item.lookUpName} value={item.lookUpId} key={index}>)
       )}  
    </Picker>
```

Comment: kumar can you pls check whether you are receiving the data from this.props.categoryList by putting a console.log before return statement

Comment: when i try to console.log i was getting array[] but in picker nothing displayed, i stopped getting values from redux store and used api now the problem is solved, i still want to know why it wasn't working.

Comment: kumar since the array is empty there is nothing to render so that it returns nothing